# OpenMP paralelize specific for loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am new to using OpenMp and I have a question.

I have a code that looks like this:

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,1000,1000> mat;
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<1000;j++){
        double aux = 0;
        // code with for loops and iterators and vectors that grow and
        // finally assign value to aux....
        mat(i,j) = aux;
   }
}
```

and I want to use OpenMp to paralelize it. In the comment part there is code with for loops. The thing is that I want to paralelize only the two for loops that i show here but not the ones that would be between double aux....mat(i,j) = aux. How can I do So? I've tryied something like

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,1000,1000> mat;
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<1000;j++){
        double aux = 0;
        // code with for loops and iterators and vectors that grow and
        // finally assign value to aux....
        mat(i,j) = aux;
   }
}
```

But the matrix is not filled with the same results as if I don't put the pragma frase. For instance with the first code mat(10,10) = 100 and with the one paralelized mat(10,10) = -1.
Can somebody give me a hint on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The code that is now shown is not thread safe?

Comment: This is potentially an interesting question but you need to provide more information if you want a good answer. You need to say more about "code with for loops and iterators and vectors that grow and". Provide some more code.